# Unable to start Genymotion virtual device, incompatible CPU in amd proccesor

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, genymotion, amd-processor

my laptop Processor is Amd and i cant run device in genymotion
in bios setting i dont have any tabs for enable Virtualization Technology 
because my processor in not intel
my processor is AMD
please help me